# Knock me on Facebook?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, phrases

When you have to ask someone to communicate with you through Facebook, how do you ask it?
"Knock me on Facebook" is a familiar term in Bangladesh. But I don't know how much appropriate it is.

Comment: It does not work in British English, and I have never seen it in American English. "[You can] contact me through/on/via Facebook" is what I would say.

Comment: “Knocked up” in AmE and probably also British E means “got pregnant”. Knocking on a door therefore isn’t a great analogy to apply to a new technology. Nobody says “dial my cell phone” either.

Comment: I love the expression BECAUSE it is different and sharp and vivid.  The standard word in, well, Facebook, is a ‘nudge’,  So you could say “Give me a nudge” or just “nudge me”.  What you must not on any account say is “knock me up”, especially if you are female.  But South Asians have as much historic right to the English language as any, and many of the greatest exponents of the English language come from there.  By all means knock me any time.

Comment: Actually the traditional meaning of 'knock up' in British English is 'wake someone in the morning by knocking on their door', which can lead to much humour/embarrassment when people learn the other meaning.

Comment: It needs to be understood that, in the US, to "knock someone" is to disparage/criticize them.

Answer (score 1):

I have to use Facebook often for my work.

I have not heard "Knock me on Facebook" in the US or Europe, but I like the expression!

I agree with the suggestion that "Contact me on Facebook" is probably the most precise and technically correct expression to use.

In the United States, I hear the following expressions often: 1) "Facebook me." 2) "Message me on Facebook". 3) "PM me on Facebook" or "Send me a PM on Facebook", where "PM" stands for "Private Message".

Answer (score 1):

In American English, we would say: *Hit me up on Facebook*.

[***Hit me up*** is slang for ***contact me***.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hit+me+up)

Comment: Actually, "hit me up" has a number of different connotations.

Comment: @HotLicks: I can think of roughly two: *contact me* and *ask me for something*. And with *on Facebook*, only one of those is possible.

Comment: Ask me for money, give me a drug hit, extortion, mugging.

Answer (score 0):

I spend a lot of time reading mail from women supposedly hitting me up because my email must be on a lot of dating sites.  The phrase "knock me" is an immediate warning that the sender is a phony who is trying to sound like they are friendly and familiar and very casual, but it is a dead giveaway that it is either a BOT or a foreign solicitation trying to get to your private info without any intention of meeting.